# PHP get parameter pulls in wrong values

Tags: php, isset

I'm trying to pull in the parameter of a URL and use that to determine what information to display on page, but for some reason the information is being read wrong. The first thing I do is check for the parameter below and assign it to $page

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page=$_GET["page"]; 
}
?>
```

I then check if the $page is equal to 2 or 3. For some reason, if I echo out $page, I get the proper value of the parameter but it displays incorrect info.

```
<?php
if(isset($page) == '2') { ?>


DISPLAY INFO A
ECHO $PAGE RETURNS 2

<?php } elseif(isset($page) == '3') { ?>

DISPLAY INFO B
ECHO $PAGE RETURNS 3

<?php } else { something here } ?>
```

For some reason, even though $page returns 3, I receive INFO A that's supposed to be displayed on page 2. Am I pulling the parameter wrong? The URL Looks like this:

```
feed.php?page=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php `isset` function return `Boolean`.
You should change code to:

```
<?php
if(isset($page) && $page== '2') {
?>
DISPLAY INFO A
ECHO $PAGE RETURNS 2
<?php } elseif(isset($page) && $page== '3') { ?>
DISPLAY INFO B
ECHO $PAGE RETURNS 3
<?php } else { something here } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
if(isset($page) == '2') {
```

It should be

```
if( $page == '2') {
```

This will only seem to work on page `1`, because `isset($page)` returns `true`, which truthy gets converted to `1`. The `isset()` function is only to check if the variable has been set or not

Answer (score 0):

```
if($page == '3')
```

Why the `isset()`? You already do that when you assign it.  Maybe this as well:

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"]; 
} else {
    $page = '0';  // or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` return a TRUE/FALSE, yet you're comparing it against normal integers. Boolean `TRUE` in mysql is equivalent to integer `1`, but will fail the rest of your tests. You need to have:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   if ($_GET['page'] == 1) { ... 1 stuff } 
   else if ($_GET['page'] == 2) { ... 2 stuff } 
}
```